# Changing a string iteratively

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write in Python a script that takes a string and returns a list of string by iteratively moves the letters in the original sequence.

For example : ACGT-->TACG -->GTAC-->CGTA-->STOP (original sequence)

I am a beginner in programming, here is what I've succeed to do

```
liste=[]
seq=list('ACGT')
nseq=list("test")
while nseq!=seq:
    for i in range (0, len(seq)):
        nseq[i]=seq[i-1]
        ''.join(nseq)
        liste.append(nseq)
```

It only returns the first step like TACG and doesn't go on.

Output : `['T', 'A', 'C', 'G']`multiple time (endless loop)

Expected output :

`TACG
GTAC
CGTA`

Comment: Please update your question with the actual output from your code, plus your required output to help us work out what the problem is.

Comment: Can you explain more about the context, this is obviously DNA, what's the bioinformatic problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am working with tandem repeats sequence. I have patterns as output of a software and want to put together all the "identical" patterns (same sequence but not cut at the same point by the software.)

Comment: You want to align the tandem repeats?

Comment: No I am just doing quantification so I just want to select one tandem (and its "brothers") and sum the number of time it has been detected.

Comment: Please update your expected outputs. It looks like there is a repeated item.

Comment: @PaulineR any reason you unaccepted  my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101272/244297)?

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to unaccept your answer. It appeared like I didn't accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to move the last element to the beginning until you come to the original sequence. For this [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and it's [`rotate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) method (which is equivalent to `d.appendleft(d.pop())`)  should be the most efficient:

```
from collections import deque

def rotations(s):
    yield s
    d = deque(s)

    for _ in range(len(d) - 1):
        d.rotate(1)
        yield ''.join(d)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for r in rotations('ACGT'):
...     print(r)
... 
ACGT
TACG
GTAC
CGTA
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution without any import.

```
def rot(s, n):
    return s[-n:] + s[:-n]

for i in range(4):
    print(rot('ACGT', i))
```

**Output**

> ACGT
>
> TACG
>
> GTAC
>
> CGTA

Answer (score 2):

```
list = []
seq = "ACGT"
for i in range(len(seq), 0, -1):
    list.append(seq[i:]+seq[:i])
# list = ['ACGT', 'TACG', 'GTAC', 'CGTA']
```

Comment: plus 1 for simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `collections.deque` and `rotate`:

```
from collections import deque

def rotator(x):
    yield x
    y = deque(x)
    for _ in range(len(y)-1):
        y.rotate(1)
        yield ''.join(y)

res = list(rotator('ACGT'))

print(res)

['ACGT', 'TACG', 'GTAC', 'CGTA']
```

Comment: upvote from me, seems like the best approach to the programmatic issue as stated

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? Don't worry I don't retaliate.. just want to know what I can improve.

Answer (score 2):

```
def move_letter_forward(string):
    str_list = [string]
    for i in range(len(string) - 1):
        str_list.append(str_list[-1][-1] + str_list[-1][:-1])
    return str_list
```

---

If you want the output to be:

```
TACG
GTAC
CGTA
```

The above code can be change to:

```
def move_letter_forward(string):
    str_list = [string]
    for i in range(len(string) - 1):
        str_list.append(str_list[-1][-1] + str_list[-1][:-1])
    return str_list[1:]
for string in move_forward('ACGT'):
        print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need rotations to be printed, have a look at this:

```
>>> s = 'ACGT'
>>> '-->'.join(s[i:]+s[0:i] for i in range(len(s),0,-1))
'ACGT-->TACG-->GTAC-->CGTA'
```

If you need in a list just omit the `'-->'.join` part:

```
>>> rotations = [s[i:]+s[0:i] for i in range(len(s),0,-1)]
>>> rotations
['ACGT', 'TACG', 'GTAC', 'CGTA']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using queue data structure.

Here is the general version

1. pop the element from the last index
2. push the element to first index
3. repeat it for the length of the input string.

I leave the implementation to you, use this as reference [Queue DS in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Here is the implementation
Code

```
from collections import deque
ip = 'ACGT'
d = deque(ip)

for i in range(len(ip)):
    temp = d.pop()
    d.appendleft(temp)
    print(''.join(d))


OUTPUT
TACG
GTAC
CGTA
ACGT
```

Comment: Well there is certainly conversion of string into list of characters in the intermediate steps.

Comment: see the implementation. this method is generic and can be used with any string